# laravel query for bewteen

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to convert the sql query to laravel query  which is working fine in sql

```
select
   a.id,
   a.assigned_user_name,
   a.lead_stage_c,
   a.meeting_start_date,
   a.call_start_date 
from
   mgl_report_targets as a 
   left join
      dcalendardate b 
      on b.datevalue = a.meeting_start_date 
   left join
      dcalendardate c 
      on c.datevalue = a.call_start_date 
where
   (
      a.lead_stage_c = 'Target-MQL'
   )
   and 
   (
      b.datevalue between '2020-07-31' and '2020-09-01'
   )
   or 
   (
      c.datevalue between '2020-07-31' and '2020-09-01'
   )
   and a.active_status = '1' 
   and a.lead_stage_c = 'Target-MQL'
```

In laravel I have tried as

```
$report_details=DB::table('mgl_report_targets')->where('active_status',1);
$report_details=$report_details->leftjoin('dcalendardate as a','a.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date::date"))->leftjoin('dcalendardate as b','b.datevalue','=',DB::raw("mgl_report_targets.call_start_date::date"));
$report_details=$report_details->where(function ($query) { 
         return $query->whereBetween('a.datevalue',['2020-07-31','2020-09-01']);
       })
 ->orWhere(function ($query) { 
        return $query->whereBetween('b.datevalue',['2020-07-31','2020-09-01']);
        }); 
$report_details=$report_details->where('mgl_report_targets.lead_stage_c','=','Target-MQL')->select('mgl_report_targets.id','mgl_report_targets.assigned_user_name','mgl_report_targets.meeting_start_date','mgl_report_targets.call_start_date','mgl_report_targets.lead_stage_c')->get();
```

but between query not query as expected.
What I did wrong.

Comment: I'm surprised your straight query is working. Mixing AND/OR clauses like that can be very confusing without parenthesis around the query blocks. You only have them around the individual queries, but nothing to group the AND/OR blocks together.

Comment: What do you mean "not query as expected". Please provide expected result with some example